# How do you create a textbox in visual Studio with c#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text, instructions

I feel kind of silly asking this question as it seems really simple, but how do I create a text box that I can type in instructions and stuff like that. I don't need the user to be able to change it, it is just to give instructions. I tried the label, but it only allows one line. I need something that can allow about a paragraph or so. Similar to the box in an installer that describes what the program does. What did I miss?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a label but set its AutoSize property to false. This allows you to size the label as you wish and it will automatically wrap the text to fit.

You can also anchor the label to the parent form to have it automatically resize and reflow the text if the user resizes the parent form.

Comment: There we go, that is what I was looking for. I forgot all about the AutoSize. And the anchor is perfect too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want a text box, but set its Read Only property to TRUE, and maybe Enabled to FALSE